# Mod Rewrite removes extension of ajax

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this rewrite rules (taken from a solution on this site) to hide .php and it works but it does not allow my ajax to work now.

```
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://domain.us/php/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://domain.us/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I only have a few pages that I actually want to hide the .php extension, so maybe there is a different way to do this. I would be fine with targeting just the pages I need and not all met conditions.

Here is my error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.us/php/get. No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://www.domain.us' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This part is new to me, so it is very confusing still, thanks

*UPDATE*
The selected answer below is correct and works, just NOT on my Godaddy server. This was tested on another server and was confirmed to work.

Comment: Open Firebug and run our requests again. Report what you see in `Net` tab.

Comment: Says 404 not found. File extension is removed unlike all the ones above it. Should be get.php and firebug only says get

Comment: Ok as per your rules `/get.php` will become `/get` but why are you getting 404? Your last rule would make it `/get.php` internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://domain.us/php/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://domain.us/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^tos/?$ tos.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^account/?$ account.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```